# simple_html_dom does not work as expected

Tags: php, web-scraping

```
$html = new \simple_html_dom();
$html -> load_file('h*ttp://xxx.com/article.html');
$res = $html->find('div[id=content]',0)->find('p');

$arr = array();//result set
foreach($res as $v){
    $arr[] = strip_tags($v->plaintext);
}
print_r($arr);//print
```

I want to scrap content from a webpage,the content is encapsulated in the <*div*> with ID valued  'content',now,I retrieve every paragraph enclosed with <*p*>,there are actually another tag <*figure*> in the div,finally I got results with both <*p*> And <*figure*>,<*figure*> should not be there and what is wrong with me?

DOM structure

div id= content
   p
   p
   figure
   p
   figure
   p
   p
div

Comment: what does the code output ?

Comment: Content in </*p> tag printed out as expected.Content inside <*figure> tag also printed out.Weird,I'm not finding the figure tag.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
$res = $html->find('#content p');
```